How to install pyaudio in spyder (anaconda)
I'm very new in Python and I'm trying to install pyaudio and run it in spyder.
Every time I run it I get the following error:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_init_.py:103 in get_pyaudio
import pyaudio


File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pyaudio_init_.py:111
import pyaudio._portaudio as pa


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio._portaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):


File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)


File c:\users\r_dua\appdata\local\programs\python\python313\lib\site-packages\speech_to_text_.py:35
reconhecer_e_transcrever()


File c:\users\r_dua\appdata\local\programs\python\python313\lib\site-packages\speech_to_text_.py:15 in reconhecer_e_transcrever
with sr.Microphone() as source:


File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_init_.py:75 in init
self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()


File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_init_.py:105 in get_pyaudio
raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")


AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

I tried different installations as:
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio

or if I do:
conda install pyaudio
I get the following mensages:

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:


package pyaudio-0.2.11-py27h0c8e037_1 requires python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed


Could not solve for environment specs The following packages are
incompatible ├─ pin-1 is installable and it requires │  └─ python
3.12.* , which can be installed; └─ pyaudio is not installable because there are no viable options    ├─ pyaudio 0.2.11 would require    │
└─ python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable
versions previously reported;    ├─ pyaudio 0.2.11 would require    │
└─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable
versions previously reported;    ├─ pyaudio 0.2.11 would require    │
└─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable
versions previously reported;    ├─ pyaudio 0.2.11 would require    │
└─ python >=3.5,<3.6.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable
versions previously reported;    ├─ pyaudio 0.2.11 would require    │
└─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable
versions previously reported;    ├─ pyaudio 0.2.11 would require    │
└─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable
versions previously reported;    └─ pyaudio 0.2.11 would require
└─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

I also installed other IDLE and in that case it works. I don't understand why it doesn't work with spyder.
Could you please give me a hand on this?
I tried different types of installations but it doesn't work.
